# How to disable natural scrolling in OS X Lion and Safari?

Tags: javascript, safari, scroll, osx-lion

Is there a way to disable the new elastic/natural scrolling in OS X Lion and Lion (+ Fluid.app) via Javascript on web pages? Use cases includes a fullscreen webapp similar to iOS webapps.

Comment: *Please* don't mess with the native UI. If users don't like it, they'll change browsers. If they do like it, why are you taking it away?

Comment: I should have been more specific: I'm working with a "fullscreen" webapp which is 100% in height and width. The content in divs scrolls but it's quite confusing as the natural scrolling allows the whole window to be "flex". It's possible to disable in iOS webapps but the same trick doesn't work with Safari.

Comment: I was told that Apple has disabled natural scrolling's bounce in iCloud apps se there should be a way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can disable the scroll bounce by settings overflow: hidden for the body element. Apple does it so with their developer docs: http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/navigation/index.html

Comment: Just an FYI - this does not seem to work for Mobile Safari.  Is there an equivalent trick for iOS devices?

Comment: Nope, on iOS you need to prevent ontouchmove for body element. See http://matt.might.net/articles/how-to-native-iphone-ipad-apps-in-javascript/ and part Preventing elastic scrolling

Comment: That does work for the page, but it also will disable scrolling divs within your page.